# Specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

When I publish my ASP.NET MVC 4, EF 5.0, Code-First Project to test or production environment following exception occurs:

(error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.)

```
    [MetadataException: Das angegebene Schema ist ungültig. Fehler: 
(0,0) : Fehler 0175: Der angegebene Speicheranbieter kann nicht in der Konfiguration gefunden werden oder ist ungültig.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +57
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +206
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders) +368
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo) +361
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration) +194
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +328
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +150
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +66
```

The database on the SQL server was created, and also the tables in the database.

On the local dev environment everything is working fine. I locally installed the same MS SQL Express 2008 R2 version as on test/production. And locally everything is working.

As I read on other with the same error (mostly with MySQL database), the error was fixed with including the binaries. But for MSSQL there are no special binaries to include (I think). And the database/tables are created, so the access to SQL server should be fine.

Here is my web.config for production/test:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NameOfContext" connectionString="Server=ServerName\MSSQL;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=Username;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
...
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="NameOfContext, Application name">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[NameOfContext, Application Name], [Name_App.Migrations.Configuration, Application Name]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="NameOfContent" />
          </parameters>
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: If it's saying the procedure can't be found, then either the procedure it needs doesn't exist, or the user doesn't have permission to see it. In situations like this, I use SQL Profile to watch exactly what's going on. Often times that gives you a lot of information about what's going on and lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, what is SQL Profile?

Comment: I meant SQL Profiler. It's a utility that comes with SQL Server's management tools. It allows you to view all activity on the server, including what commands are being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "solved" the problem: I created a new project and copied all the code to the new project, where the problem no longer appeared.
Maybe it was a problem with the auto-migration. Altough I run 'update-database -targetmigration:0' and recreate all migrations.